# get a field value of an object in ng-options and filter other

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have create two lists.

1)contains the service names

2)contains the product names assigned to service names

There are IDs to match the products on the  assigmented services.

```js
app.controller('loadProductServicesCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.services = [
        {"ServiceID": 1, "ServiceName": "Τηλεπικοινωνίες"},
        {"ServiceID": 2, "ServiceName": "Ενέργεια"},
        {"ServiceID": 3, "ServiceName": "Ιδιωτική Ασφάλεια Υγείας"}
    ];

    $scope.products = [
        {
            "ProductID": 9,
            "ServiceID": 1,
            "ServiceName": "Τηλεπικοινωνίες",
            "ProductName": "Business 500",
            "ProductProfit": 40,
            "ProductTooltip":""
        },
        {
            "ProductID": 10,
            "ServiceID": 2,
            "ServiceName": "Τηλεπικοινωνίες",
            "ProductName": "Business 1000",
            "ProductProfit": 50,
            "ProductTooltip": ""
        },
        { 
            "ProductID": 11,
            "ServiceID": 3,
            "ServiceName": "Τηλεπικοινωνίες",
            "ProductName": "Business W",
            "ProductProfit": 75,
            "ProductTooltip": ""
        }
    ];
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="selectpicker" class="margin-r-5 form-label">Select Service</label>
  <select data-ng-model="myService" data-ng-options="service as service.ServiceName for service in services" class="selectpicker services">
      <option value="">Select Service</option>                
  </select> 
</div>

<div class="form-group products">
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary checkbox-inline" ng-repeat="x in products">
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{ x.ProductID }}" value="option1">
    <label for="{{ x.ProductID }}"> {{ x.ProductName }} </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to filter the products with service ID which is selected. I tryed to use the ng-model on the select element, but it didnt works. 
Any advices?

Comment: i can not see you have implemented filter.

Answer (score 0):

You should do

`ng-repeat="x in products|filter:{ServiceID:myService.ServiceID}"`

**Running Snippet**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('loadProductServicesCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.services = [{
    "ServiceID": 1,
    "ServiceName": "Τηλεπικοινωνίες"
  }, {
    "ServiceID": 2,
    "ServiceName": "Ενέργεια"
  }, {
    "ServiceID": 3,
    "ServiceName": "Ιδιωτική Ασφάλεια Υγείας"
  }];
  $scope.products = [{
    "ProductID": 9,
    "ServiceID": 1,
    "ServiceName": "Τηλεπικοινωνίες",
    "ProductName": "Business 500",
    "ProductProfit": 40,
    "ProductTooltip": ""
  }, {
    "ProductID": 10,
    "ServiceID": 2,
    "ServiceName": "Τηλεπικοινωνίες",
    "ProductName": "Business 1000",
    "ProductProfit": 50,
    "ProductTooltip": ""
  }, {
    "ProductID": 11,
    "ServiceID": 3,
    "ServiceName": "Τηλεπικοινωνίες",
    "ProductName": "Business W",
    "ProductProfit": 75,
    "ProductTooltip": ""
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="loadProductServicesCtrl">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="selectpicker" class="margin-r-5 form-label">Select Service</label>
    <select data-ng-model="myService" data-ng-options="service as service.ServiceName for service in services track by service.ServiceID" class="selectpicker services">
      <option value="">Select Service</option>

    </select>
  </div>
 Selected Id : {{ myService.ServiceID}}
  <div class="form-group products" ng-repeat="x in products|filter:{ServiceID:myService.ServiceID}">
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" id="{{ x.ProductID }}" value="option1">
      <label for="{{ x.ProductID }}">{{x.ProductName}}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ChristosKesisis Is it helpful?

Comment: Works fine, Thank you!

Comment: When the first option with name "Select Service" is selected all the products is shown. Can you tell how to hide all the products when the first option is slsected?

Answer (score 0):

Use filter at `ng-repeat`

```
ng-repeat="x in products | filter:{ ServiceID: myService.ServiceID }"
```

demo https://jsfiddle.net/vorant/m330mp3a/